# SQL select statement with AND and OR operators issue

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, sql-server-2000, ado

I'm fetching records from the SQL Server 2000 database using Classic ASP. This is what the code I have used.

**ASP Code:**

```
<form name="search" method="post" onsubmit="return attention();">
<table width="60%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><h1 style="color:#003399;">Search for Certificate of Analysis</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="bottom">Product number <sup style="color:#EE0000;font-size:1.3em">*</sup></td>
    <td valign="bottom">Lot number</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="30%" valign="top">
        <input type="text" name="input1" size="20"/>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="text" size="20" name="input2"/> 
        <input style="background-color:#ffffff;border:0px;cursor:pointer" size="10" type="submit" name="sub" value=">>" />
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
<%
    if request.Form("sub") <> "" then
    Dim fname, lname
    fname= request.Form("input1")
    lname= request.Form("input2")
    session("n") = fname & lname
    sql = "Select * from search where cat_no_batch_no LIKE '"&request.Form("input1")&"%' OR cat_no_batch_no='"&session("n")&"'"
    rs.open sql, con, 1, 2
    if rs.eof then

    response.write("Please provide a valid Cat No.")    

    else



            do while not rs.eof
        %>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="60%" style="margin:0 auto; border-collapse:collapse;border-color:#999999">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%"><%=rs("cat_no_batch_no")%></td>
                <td width="10%">Click to open <a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/search1/<%=rs("pdf_path")%>"><%=rs("cat_no_batch_no")%></a></td>
            </tr>
            </table>

        <%
            rs.movenext
            loop
        end if
    rs.close
    end if
%>
</form>
```

Above the LIKE statement works as expected and displays multiple records which contains similar  **Cat No.**.
Issue rises when I input a **Cat No** in first Input box and **Lot Number** in another. My desired output should have been just a single record to display as I have given **Cat No.** and **Lot Number** , but it shows multiple records.

I have provided the images to be more clear.

1. In this image below I have put **6106021** as the **product number** so it displays two entries.
   [image]
2. In this image I have put **6106021** as the **product number** and **218111** as the Lot Number, it shows two entries instead of 1. This is what the issue, it should show one entry as Lot number are unique while cat number can be the same.
   [image]

Comment: Try `AND` instead of `OR`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can write two separate SQL queries, according as the "Lot number" is provided or not.
Your code may goes like below:

```
if lname = "" then
    sql = "Select * from search where cat_no_batch_no LIKE '"&request.Form("input1")&"%'" 
else
    sql = "Select * from search where cat_no_batch_no LIKE '"&session("n")&"%'"
end if
```

I hope this could help

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, thanks for your reply. Still looking for a workaround.@naoki

Answer (score 2):

Read your question to yourself and think about what you are saying:

You state *"My desired output should have been just a single record to display as I have given Cat No. and Lot Number"*

But in your SQL you write `where cat_no_batch_no LIKE '"&request.Form("input1")&"%' OR cat_no_batch_no='"&session("n")&"'`

The key words are AND vs. OR

In your mind you are thinking both conditions must be true, but your query says otherwise. If you want both conditions to be true then you must use the AND operator.

Naoki is on to something - you are going to have to modify your SQL depending upon which criteria are specified.

Comment: thanks for the reply but still confunsed on how to implement it.